# Spark HOF: reduce not identified

Tags: apache-spark

While experimenting with spark's HOFs, I see transform, filter, exists etc working fine. But reduce is throwing error.

Code is as:

```
spark.sql("SELECT" +
      " celsius," +
      " reduce(celsius,0,(t, acc) -> t + acc, acc -> (acc div size(celsius) * 9 div 5) + 32 ) as avgFahrenheit" +
      " FROM celsiusView")
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Undefined function: 'reduce'. This function is neither a registered
> temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database
> 'default'.;

Comment: How are you running? I had no issue with this.

Comment: Which version of Spark?

Comment: Spark version is 3.0.0-preview2.

Comment: no issue with databricks spark 3.2.1

Comment: I cannot find a reduce function [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html). Do you probably mean [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#aggregate)?

Comment: @werner, right. Book I am following has reduce. Now I see its aggregate in 3.0.0. Thanks a lot.